# After upgrading to PostgreSQL default value for ImageField does not work (Django)

Tags: django, postgresql

Since shifting to PostgreSQL (from SQLite) the default value for `ImageField` does not work. If I select and upload the image manually everything is fine. Also other fields default values work fine as well. This is done from admin while adding a new post.

`models.py`:

```
preview_content = models.TextField(max_length=150, default="This is the default preview")
preview_image = models.ImageField(default="img/blog/default_preview.jpg", upload_to="img/blog")
```

First one works fine, second one does not. Does anyone know what the problem is?

EDIT: Additional info

Django==3.1.3; Postgres==13.1

When I want to add new post, instead of having the default preview image path `img/blog/default_preview.jpg` it says `No file chosen`. While the default value is displayed correctly for the upper field.

[image]

Comment: Django version? Postgres version? The type of the field in the Postgres table? Define does not work?

Comment: I will update the question with the info

Comment: The field type in Postgres table? Does `"img/blog/default_preview.jpg"` exist?

Comment: At first it was blank, but when I refreshed it now to check again, it has updated. And now it is also displayed in the page as well. Oddly, now everything works fine, although it still says `No file chosen` when I want to add a new post, but when I save it, everything is ok. Good enough for me. Thank you for taking interest in the question I would probably spent plenty of time looking for the solution elsewhere.

Comment: I'm guessing you will have to click on `Choose File` and select the default.

Comment: Actually there is no need. I just leave it as it is, save it, and it works. I guess maybe there is some problem with displaying path in admin.